# Simple MVC5 webpage architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, architecture, viewmodel, mvc-editor-templates

I am wondering what the best approach is to build a simple webpage like [this mockflow layout](http://app.mockflow.com/view/BD69D71902C34264F75DB79428B486DE).
It's not that I am new to MVC itself. I just don't know the common way of building pages. See the following code how I would approach it. Note, I am only interested in the viewmodels and views.

ViewModels

```
public class FoodModel
{
    public CategoryModel CategoryModel { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Pizzas")]
    public PizzaModel PizzaModel { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Sandwiches")]
    public SandwichModel SandwichModel { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Meats")]
    public MeatModel MeatModel { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryModel
{
    public int SelectedCategoryId {get; set; }
    public string RandomField { get; set; }
}

public class PizzaModel
{
    public IList<PizzaRow> PizzaRows {get; set; }
}

public class PizzaRow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class SandwichModel
{
    public IList<SandwichRow> SandwichRows {get; set; }
}

public class SandwichRow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ingredients { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class MeatModel
{
    public IList<MeatRow> MeatRows {get; set; }
}

public class MeatRow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Animal { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Index-view and EditorTemplates for each Model and its Rows.

```
<!-- ~Views/Food/Index.cshtml -just the nessecary razor-code. don't mind the layout-->
@Model FoodModel

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CategoryModel) @*For generating the top bar*@
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(x => PizzaModel)</div>@*For grid name 'Pizzas'*@
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PizzaModel)
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(x => SandwichModel)</div>@*For grid name 'Sandwiches'*@
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SandwichModel)
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(x => MeatModel)</div>@*For grid name 'Meats'*@
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MeatModel)

<!-- ~Views/Food/EditorTemplates/CategoryModel.cshtml -just the nessecary razor-code. don't mind the layout-->
@Model CategoryModel

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId, ViewBag.Categories)
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.RandomField)

<!-- ~Views/Food/EditorTemplates/PizzaModel.cshtml -just the nessecary razor-code. don't mind the layout-->
@Model PizzaModel

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PizzaRows.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PizzaRows.FirstOrDefault().Ingredients)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        Html.EditorFor(x => x.PizzaRows);
    </table>

<!-- ~Views/Food/EditorTemplates/SandwichModel.cshtml -just the nessecary razor-code. don't mind the layout-->
@Model SandwichModel

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PizzaRows.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PizzaRows.FirstOrDefault().Ingredients)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PizzaRows.FirstOrDefault().Price)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        Html.EditorFor(x => x.SandwichRows);
    </table>


<!-- ~Views/Food/EditorTemplates/MeatModel.cshtml -just the nessecary razor-code. don't mind the layout-->
@Model MeatModel

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PizzaRows.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PizzaRows.FirstOrDefault().Animal)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PizzaRows.FirstOrDefault().Weight)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    Html.EditorFor(x => x.MeatRows);
    </table>


<!-- ~Views/Food/EditorTemplates/PizzaRow.cshtml -just the nessecary razor-code. don't mind the layout-->
@Model PizzaRow

    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Ingredients)</td>
    </tr>

<!-- ~Views/Food/EditorTemplates/SandwichRow.cshtml -just the nessecary razor-code. don't mind the layout-->
@Model SandwichRow

    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Ingredients)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Price)</td>
    </tr>

<!-- ~Views/Food/EditorTemplates/MeatRow.cshtml -just the nessecary razor-code. don't mind the layout-->
@Model MeatRow

    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Animal)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Weight)</td>
    </tr>
```

Would this be a decent approach or am I a fool for using those EditorFor's instead of Partials. Or maybe there is other advice and tips. Thanks for your time and advice.

Comment: Why exactly do you think you're a fool for using the tools the framework gives you to do exactly what you're trying to do?  Using partials for templating would be the foolish choice.

Answer (score 0):

The only comment i'd make is that you seem to be using EdtiorTemplates for displaying data... Use DisplayTemplates instead.  You should probably also use `DisplayNameFor()` for your table headers instead of LabelFor on a first item.  This is what DisplayNameFor is.. well.. for.